# No me pinta el data de la api

Tags: nodejs, api, axios, expo, retorno

Estoy intentando consumir una api con *axios*, que al darle clic al botón me pinte la data de la api, pero solo me pinta el botón y al darle clic no me genera nada. En la consola sí me muestra la data de la api pero en el emulador ya no me pinta nada.

```
import axios from "axios";
import {SafeAreaView, Button} from "react-native";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const baseURL = "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1";

export default function App() {
      
    const [descargarUsuarios, setDescargarUsuarios]= useState()
    useEffect(() => {
          axios.get(baseURL).then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data);          
          });
          }, 
          []);

          return(
            <SafeAreaView>          
            <Button
                color="pink"
                title="PUSH"
                onPress= {descargarUsuarios}
            />                    
            </SafeAreaView>) 
  };
```

Comment: Donde estás  intentando que te pinte la data? yo solo veo un `console.log` (y por eso dices que en consola si te muestra la data) que mas esperas que pase?

Comment: Espero que cuando lo ejecute en expo, me pinte la infor en el emulador al darle clic en el botón :(